# Is there a way to unmount and remount a canvas?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I don't know if this has already been asked.

Say I have a container, `<div id="cy"><div/>`,

I then initialise a canvas on it
`var cy = cytoscape({container: document.getElementById('cy')});`

Is it possible to unmount this canvas and add another in it's place? For example.

`cy.unmount();
var cy2 = cytoscape({container: document.getElementById('cy')});`

I am asking since I wish to use multiple cytoscape canvas in tab-able pages. Any suggestions much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you create a new instance on the same div you already made an instance on, then the old instance is automatically destroyed.

Comment: OK, but what if I want to keep the state of the hidden canvas intact. Right now I have multiple containers each with their own cytoscape instances, and I just have `display: none` on all but one of them (the one I want to be displayed). Will this have a big performance impact? Thanks

Comment: If you don't want to destroy an instance, don't overwrite it.  Create a new DOM container per graph.  Re. performance, you'll use more memory as compared to recycling.